# Letting HTML5 access Android's camera using KitKat

Tags: android-camera, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using the following code which works with previous android versions to access the camera and phone files though a webview however it doesn't seem to work when I'm running it using KitKat. I also don't want to use phonegap to solve the problem. I'm not sure why this is happening if anyone can suggest a solution I would really appreciate it

```
public class Home extends Activity {

     //private Button button;
    private WebView webView;
    final Activity activity = this;
    public Uri imageUri;

    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 2888;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        //Get webview 
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        // Define url that will open in webview 
        String webViewUrl = "http://www.nutritics.com/test.html";

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError (WebView webView, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });

        // Javascript inabled on webview  
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Other webview options
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        //Other webview settings
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 

        //Load url in webview
        webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl);

        startWebView(); 

    }

    private void startWebView() {

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType){  

                // Update message
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

                try{    

                    // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

                    File imageStorageDir = new File(
                                           Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                           Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                                           , "AndroidExampleFolder");

                    if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                        imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                    }

                    // Create camera captured image file path and name 
                    File file = new File(
                                    imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                                    + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) 
                                    + ".jpg");

                    mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file); 

                    // Camera capture image intent
                    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                                                  android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");

                    // Create file chooser intent
                    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

                    // Set camera intent to file chooser 
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                                           , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

                    // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

                  }
                 catch(Exception e){
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:"+e, 
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }

            }

            // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }

            //openFileChooser for other Android versions
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, 
                                       String acceptType, 
                                       String capture) {

                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }

            // The webPage has 2 filechoosers and will send a 
            // console message informing what action to perform, 
            // taking a photo or updating the file

            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {  

                onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
                return true;
            }

            public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
                //Log.d("androidruntime", "Show console messages, Used for debugging: " + message);

            }
        });   // End setWebChromeClient
     }

    // Return here when file selected from camera or from SDcard

    @Override 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) { 

     if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
     {  

            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;

            }

           Uri result=null;

           try{
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                    result = null;

                } else {

                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData(); 
                } 
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e,
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;

     }

    }

    // Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed

    @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(webView.canGoBack()) {

            webView.goBack();

        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```